# SQL to NHibernate HQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I am new to hibernate and hql. Can anyone help me what is the hql equivalent for the below query?

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,
LEFT(CAST([run_date] AS VARCHAR),4) + '-' +  
SUBSTRING(CAST([run_date] AS VARCHAR),5,2) + '-' + 
SUBSTRING(CAST([run_date] AS VARCHAR),7,2) + ' ' + 
LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([run_time] AS VARCHAR),6),2) + ':' + 
SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([run_time] AS VARCHAR),6),3,2) + ':' + 
SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([run_time] AS VARCHAR),6),5,2)
,121)
FROM sysjobhistory
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would not create a HQL query for that. Instead i would just use simple hql to read `run_time` and use a ResultTransfomer with some Date Fromater to get final result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually this is a subquery in the main query.

Comment: The query will be something like AND STARTTIME IN (ABOVE QUERY>

Comment: Then you still have the possibility to make it two queries.

Answer (score 0):

You're really torturing NHibernate here. Granted, `sysobjhistory` has somewhat of a strange schema with `run_date` and `run_time` being `int`s, but what you're doing is not a NHibernate way.

The way I'd do that is I'd write a custom [`IUserType`](http://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype/) to transform between native `DateTime` instances and these two columns.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am using the above query as a subquery in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Since sysjobhistory is specific to a particular RDBMS, it might be a good idea to try to define that as a stored procedure or user function in the DB itself, and then simply call that from HQL.

Comment: Hi Thank you. Will try your option. Currently i am using ADO.Net to execute directly the SQL query.